# Append new value to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the below Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Value> DictFoundExpected = new Dictionary<string, Value>();

        public struct Value
        {
            string code;
            int found;
            int expected;
            public Value(int f,int exp,string code)
            {
                this.found=f;
                this.expected=exp;
                this.code = code;
            }
        }
```

And script:

```
while (sqlreader.Read())
 {
    if (DictFoundExpected.ContainsKey(sqlreader[1].ToString()))
     {
       DictFoundExpected[sqlreader[1].ToString()]=?????// I want to increase Value.expected by 1
     }
     else
     {
       DictFoundExpected.Add(sqlreader[1].ToString(),new Value(0,0,sqlreader[0].ToString()));

     }
                }
```

I am stuck on how to incremenent the value of `Value.expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (sqlreader.Read())
{
  string key = sqlreader[1].ToString();
  if (DictFoundExpected.ContainsKey(key))
  {
    Value v = DictFoundExpected[key];
    DictFoundExpected[key]= new Value(v.Found, v.Expected + 1, v.Code);
  }
  else {
    DictFoundExpected.Add(key,new Value(0,0,sqlreader[1].ToString()));
  }
}
```

This is assuming your Value struct has properties like:

```
public int Found { get { return found; } }
public int Expected { get { return expected; } }
public string Code { get { return code; } }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am stuck on how to incremenent the value of Value.expected

just add a method to your `struct value` which increase the `Value.expected` like:

```
public struct Value
{
    string code;
    int found;
    int expected;
    public void IncreaseExpected()
    {
        expected++;
    }
    public Value(int f, int exp, string code)
    {
        this.found = f;
        this.expected = exp;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

and use it like (i changed the code slightly, to read the `sqlreader field`only once):

```
while (sqlreader.Read())
{
    String currentCode = sqlreader[1].ToString();
    if (DictFoundExpected.ContainsKey(currentCode))
    {
       DictFoundExpected[currentCode].IncreaseExpected();
    }
    else
    {
      DictFoundExpected.Add(currentCode,new Value(0,0,currentCode));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I upvoted but I just prefer Denis approach